# EmailIntent going back to previous activity

Tags: android, email

I have an activity with a button that sends a pre-defined email.  The button is working and the email is sent, but when completed it goes back to the previous activity.  I want it to remain on the same activity.

Is there a modification that's needed to my code or am I suppose to put the code in an activity designed just for sending emails?

```
    ImageView btnTest = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageButtontest);
    btnTest.setClickable(true);
    btnTest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            String[] recipients = new String[]{"android@someemail.com"};

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My email body text");

            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

            Activityname.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

            finish();
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Take care,
Shannon

Comment: why are you call 
            finish();? try to comment that line and run again let me know what happen?

Comment: That worked!  I found the snippet online.  Didn't know that finish() closed the activity.  Appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
finish();
```

this line closes the activity, which redirects your app to previous activity. so removing this line , should help you solve the problem of staying in the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `finish();` from this code